# Shortcut to move email to multiple folders in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

In Gmail, I use labels to categorize emails. These labels can be easily added by selecting an email pressing `x` and adding labels using `l`. Moreover, labels are displayed for each email in the inbox.

In Thunderbird, [Gmail labels correspond to **folders**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail#w_understanding-gmail-labels-and-thunderbird-folders).

- Is there a shortcut to move a selected email to **multiple** folders at the same time, thereby adding the corresponding Gmail labels? [This addon](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quick-folder-move/) lets me use a shortcut to move an email to one folder.
- Is there a way I can see at a glance, for emails in the inbox, in which folders they currently reside?

Comment: I want to do something similar but for a protonmail setup.